# Django REST - Serialize User.get_all_permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building an application with a Django Rest backend, and a VueJS front end and am working through authorization and authentication.  I have the authentication working well, but am a bit stuck on letting the front end (VueJS) know what the user has authorization to do in terms of Add/Change/View/Delete for a model.  For example, if a user cannot add a customer, I don't want to show the 'Add Customer button'.

Working through the Django docs, and solutions on StackOverflow, I believe the simplest way is to send the user's permissions from Django to VueJS.

The 'best'/'simplest' way I can see to get the permissions is with the following:

```
    userModel = User.objects.get(request.user)
    return User.get_all_permissions(userModel)
```

Where I am stuck is exactly where to put this logic and how to serialize it.  Does the above belong in the View, Serializer, other?  Up until now, I have only been working with Models (ModelSerializers and ModelViews), but I don't believe this falls into this category.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this logic to views, because the views are used to implement these kinds of logic.
Actually, you don't want to use `serializers` here, because of the response of **`.get_all_permissions()`** method is already in serialized form
Apart from that, your provided code is ***not good*** (it's clearly bad). It should be as below,

```
return request.user.get_all_permissions()
```

because, you'll get current logged-in user's instance through **`request.user`**, to get his/her permissions, you all need to call the `get_all_permissions()` method

**Example**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


@permission_classes(IsAuthenticated, )
@api_view()
def my_view(request):
    logged_in_user = request.user
    return Response(data=logged_in_user.get_all_permissions())
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I tried adding the above to my existing views.py file, and received the following error (so I am not understanding a step, or am missing something:  
AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

Please advise what I have missed.

Comment: This view is a ***standalone*** snippet. You all want to do is, c&p the code in your view, and mention the view ***properly*** in your `urls.py`

Comment: Thanks again.  I changed the URL:
From: router.register('permissions_view', views.permission_view)
To:     url(r'permissions_view', views.permission_view, name='permissions_view'),
and it worked very well.  
I lost the 'browseable API' functionality, but that may be by design.
I appreciate your help with this

Comment: can you show the current setup of your views and urls? (add those things to question)